# cygwin awk print adds strange character to filename

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin on a Windows machine to grab some information from a remote Linux machine and write the result to a file. Here is my command:

```
ssh user@remotemachine ps -aef | grep vnc | grep -v grep | awk '{print "<size>"$11"<\/size>""\n""<colorDepth>"$13"<\/colorDepth>"}' > myfile.txt
```

However, when I then run

```
ls -l
```

on the directory where myfile.txt was written, it shows that the name of the file is actually **myfile.txt?**  (with the added question mark). Where did that extra character come from and how can I get the print code to name the file correctly as simply myfile.txt

I would just run another command such as

```
mv myfile.txt? myfile.txt
```

or

```
mv myfile.txt^M myfile.txt
```

but in my bash script neither seems to find the file to rename it (though interestingly I can from the terminal (not in the script) start typing

```
mv myf
```

and then tab to complete the finding of the file, then finish the line with a new file name and that successfully renames the file.

Comment: No file name problem in my cygwin, the name `myfile.txt` is correct. One recommend to use printf in awk command: `ssh user@remotemachine ps -aef | grep vnc | grep -v grep | awk '{printf "<size>%s</size>\n<colorDepth>%s</colorDepth>\n",$11,$13}' > myfile.txt`

Comment: Is the command in a script? You might want to see the output of `od -cx <script>` and check if there is a non-printable character at the end of the filename

Comment: @BMW the file is created by shell, not awk so changing print to printf cannot affect the result

Comment: I just tried printf, but same result.  The command is in a bash script run by cygwin saving to a windows filesystem. I'm pretty sure it might have something to do with the file not being closed correctly, but not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your script uses Windows-style line endings.  The end of the line *looks* like

```
... myfile.txt
```

but it's really:

```
... myfile.txt\r\n
```

where `\r\n` is the Windows CR-LF line ending.  Which is how lines in Windows text files are supposed to end, but the shell doesn't recognize Windows-style line endings. It sees a valid line of text, but it sees the CR character as part of the line. So it treats `"myfile.txt\r"` as the file name.

How did you create the bash script file? If you used a Windows native editor, that explains the line endings.

Many editors (vim included) will automatically adapt to the line endings of a file, so you may not be able to delete the extra `\r` from your editor.

And `ls` displays non-printable characters like CR as `?`.

Running `file` on the script will probably tell you about the line endings.

Filter the script through the `dos2unix` command. (Read the man page first; unlike most text filters, `dos2unix` updates its input file rather than writing to `stdout`.)

This should also work:

```
mv foo.sh foo.sh.bad
tr -d '\r' < foo.sh.bad > foo.sh
chmod +x foo.sh
```

(I created a backup copy first just in case something goes wrong, so you don't clobber your script.)

Comment: You nailed it. I originally created the .sh file in Notepad++ on Windows. I used vi to create a new script file and pasted the text from the original file into that and ran it, and the ? issue disappeared. Thanks very much, this one had me confused for too long!

Comment: I figured this out but it still does not explain why every oother script I write in cygwin works fine, but for some reason, the last awk column is getting a ^M.

Comment: @KenIngram We can't tell without knowing how you created the failing script. What does `file name-of-script` tell you?

Comment: Found the solution by posting the question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563805/66117

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ssh user@remotemachine ps -aef | grep vnc | grep -v grep | awk '{print "<size>"$11"<\/size>""\n""<colorDepth>"$13"<\/colorDepth>"}' > myfile.txt
```

can be rewritten to:

```
ssh user@remotemachine ps -aef | awk '/[v]nc/ {print "<size>"$11"<\/size>""\n""<colorDepth>"$13"<\/colorDepth>"}' > myfile.txt
```

---

To prevent `grep` to not find it self in `ps` use `[first letter]`

```
grep vnc | grep -v grep
grep [v]nc
```

and since `awk` can do this

```
awk '/[v]nc/ {some code}'
```